# I am migrating to postgres and I am getting syntax error when i am declaring for type

Tags: postgresql

```
type rec_tab1 is table of obj1;
```

> ```
> ERROR: syntax error at or near "IS"
> LINE 70: TYPE rec_tabi IS TABLE OF rec_obj1
> ```

I don't what to change.

Comment: Where [in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/index.html) did you find that syntax

Comment: That's not a valid type definition, is it? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype.html

Comment: FYI, tables in Postgres already have an associated composite type. See [Row/Composite types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html) *8.16.1. Declaration of Composite Types*  "Whenever you create a table, a composite type is also automatically created, with the same name as the table, to represent the table's row type."

Comment: I am guessing you are migrating from Oracle. In Oracle the statement `type rec_tab1 is table of obj1;` creates a collection of the type `obj1`.  Postgres does not have collections, the closet being an array, and you do not need an independent definition. In Oracle you declare `variable rec_tab1` after defining the collection. In Postgres declare `variable obj1[]`.  If not migrating from Oracle then a few details would be useful.